# Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Tags: html, angularjs, nebular

Basically the same thing as
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onkeyup

But I am getting this error for some reason.

HTML

```
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    Enter your name: 
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
  </nb-card-body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("fname");
      x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    </script>
</nb-card>
```

[image: Error]
[image: Nb Card]

Same error without the nebular library:
HTML

```
<html>
<body>
  Enter your name: 
  <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("fname");
      x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

I have tried many other stack overflow solutions and they do not work. I am hoping to not use JQuery. This should have worked but it doesn't. I follow the other W3 School examples and get the same error.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine as it is running perfectly in my editor, you should try clearing cache and doing a hard reset, and then restarting your browser should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how to code in AngularJS. Make use of the platform's baked-in functionality - like using [ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick),  [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)

In this case, I think the solution is as easy as using a CSS class to force the uppercase, but still, I hope this helps.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.fname = "";
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
      console.log($scope.fname)
    }
  }]);
```

```css
.ucase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <nb-card>
    <nb-card-header>
      Enter your name:
    </nb-card-header>
    <nb-card-body>
      <input type="text" ng-model="fname" class='ucase' ng-keyup="myFunction()">
    </nb-card-body>
  </nb-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

your code seems to work fine here.  What's the problem?

```html
<nb-card>
  <nb-card-header>
    Enter your name: 
  </nb-card-header>
  <nb-card-body>
    <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
  </nb-card-body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("fname");
      x.value = x.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    </script>
</nb-card>
```

Comment: I am not sure either, I get this error popping up in the console (F12):
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

Comment: there must be something else wrong with your code.  What you posted works fine with no errors.  Post your entire page

Comment: That is odd, that is the entire code for that one html file. I created it separately for testing purposes.

Comment: @DCR - no, angularJS doesn’t work with scope that way. OP’s code doesn’t work for that very reason